# function only runs when input !== null

Tags: javascript, null

I am creating this simple Todo-list.  Its working fine I just want to add a condition of if 
so that the function would work only when there is a text in the inpute (if input.value !== null) otherwise it will change the border of the input to red,.here is the js code

```
//Selectors
const todoInput = document.querySelector('.todo-input');
const todoButton = document.querySelector('.todo-btn');
const todoContainer = document.querySelector('.todo-container');
const todoList = document.querySelector('.todo-list');

//Event Listners
todoButton.addEventListener('click', addTodo)

//Functions
function addTodo(event){ 
    //prevent form from submiting    
    event.preventDefault();
    // todo-div
    const todoDiv = document.createElement("div");
    todoDiv.classList.add("todo");
    // creat li
    const newTodo = document.createElement("li");
    newTodo.innerText = todoInput.value;
    newTodo.classList.add('todo-list');
    todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);
    // check mark button
    const completedButton = document.createElement('button');
    completedButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';
    completedButton.classList.add('complete-btn');
    todoDiv.appendChild(completedButton);
    // trash button
    const trashButton = document.createElement('button');
    trashButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
    trashButton.classList.add('trash-btn');
    todoDiv.appendChild(trashButton);
    // aapend to the to do list
    todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);
    todoInput.value = null
}
```

Where should I add the `if` statement because where ever I put it, it creates the div with Li in it and pushes it to the screen?

Comment: where should i add the if statement because where ever i put it , it create the div with Li in it an push it to screen. thanks

Comment: `value` is never `null`. If the user hasn't entered anything it will be an empty string `""`.

Comment: Put it around the entire function body.

Comment: if(todoInput.value !== null){
 function addTodo(event){ 
  
}
like this

Comment: That checks the value when you're defining the function, not when the function runs.

Answer (score 1):

Just exit the function without doing anything if the value is empty.

```
function addTodo(event){ 

   event.preventDefault();

   if (event.target.value === '')
     return;

  ...
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `if` statement around everything after `event.preventDefault();`.

Also, compare with `""` rather than `null`. The `value` property is always a string.

```
function addTodo(event){ 
    //prevent form from submiting    
    event.preventDefault();
    if (todoInput.value !== "") {
        // todo-div
        const todoDiv = document.createElement("div");
        todoDiv.classList.add("todo");
        // creat li
        const newTodo = document.createElement("li");
        newTodo.innerText = todoInput.value;
        newTodo.classList.add('todo-list');
        todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);
        // check mark button
        const completedButton = document.createElement('button');
        completedButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';
        completedButton.classList.add('complete-btn');
        todoDiv.appendChild(completedButton);
        // trash button
        const trashButton = document.createElement('button');
        trashButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
        trashButton.classList.add('trash-btn');
        todoDiv.appendChild(trashButton);
        // aapend to the to do list
        todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);
        todoInput.value = ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

```
function addTodo(event) { 
    //prevent form from submiting    
    event.preventDefault();

     if (!todoInput.value) {
         todoInput.classList.add('class-of-red-border');
     } else {
         // Your code
     }
}
```

Also you might want to remove red-border when user tries to enter something

So add this code also

```
todoButton.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    if (todoInput.value.length) {
        todoInput.classList.remove('class-of-red-border');
    } else {
        todoInput.classList.add('class-of-red-border');
    }
})
```